# Point value Change after projection - USGS DEM Raster VS Imagery Layer from Esri

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, dem, remote-sensing

I'm working on a project that requires National level DEM data, and Esri are providing the imagery layer
(https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0383ba18906149e3bd2a0975a0afdb8e).

1. For the most part, the extracted point values from the USGS raster and the Esri imagery layer are very close
2. However, when I project those raster’s (WGS 1984 Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere), the point value difference between projected rasters from USGS and Esri differ significantly.

I tried various geographical transformations and resampling methods but received no improvement.

What could be the cause of this, and how should I proceed?

Comment: Please elaborate on "...the point value difference between projected raster’s from USGS and ESRI differs significantly." What is different?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @Pointdump                                                                        
I created few random points and extracted multi values to points, the values from projected rasters from USGS and ESRI is not matching for more than 20% of points and the value difference ranges from 0 to 45